# Giving validations for drop down boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add validations in my form. But I don't know where I am making mistake.
I have looked different examples from different sites.
They works fine with the jsfiddle solution but when I implement them in my application, they are not working.
My fiddle link is
http://jsfiddle.net/jq4V8/

Can any one please suggest where I am making mistake.
In application I am using this js file:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: The Jsfiddle seems to be working for me , which browser are u working with

Comment: The Jsfiddle works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you do not include external javascript file for validation. Please download the validation js files **jquery.validate.min.js** and **additional-methods.js** from:

[jquery.validate.min.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js) and [additional-methods.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js)

and copy into **js** folder and include the files:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>    
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i have done a small change in jsfiddle where i would like to display errors in red color but its not happening either in jsfiddle nor in application. Is the location of div is mistaken. For reference use this link http://jsfiddle.net/cf8SL/

Comment: Please put the div inside of td.

Comment: If I place inside td then also it is not showing color.